# no constructor that takes 0 arguments- but thats not true?

Tags: c#, constructor

I have made the following code in a c# project:

```
private void RandAddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int numberOfItems = int.Parse(amountItems.Text);
    CreateDataSet.CreateDataSet create = new CreateDataSet.CreateDataSet();
    create.CreateItems(numberOfItems);
}
```

as you can see am trying to use the CreateItems in the CreateDataSet class.
The problem is that i get the folowing error

> 'CreateDataSet.CreateDataSet' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

but in the CreateDataSet class i have the following constructor:

```
public CreateDataSet() {

}
```

Why is this not working?

Thank You

Comment: if CreateDataSet is external dll then rebuild it and refresh the reference...

Comment: Can you show a bit more code? For example the class CreateDataSet.

Comment: CreateDataSet.CreateDataSet create = new CreateDataSet.CreateDataSet();       Your namespace and class names should be different. This causes ambiguity.

Comment: Btw your class name is bad. It sounds like a method, and not like a class name, since it describes an action. Call it `DataSetBuilder` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
 CreateDataSet create = new CreateDataSet();
```

Instead of:

```
 CreateDataSet.CreateDataSet create = new CreateDataSet.CreateDataSet();
```

Comment: Then I get the error 'CreateDataSet' is a 'namespace' bit is used like a 'type' :(

Comment: @JonasHansen As suggested in one of the answers, please change either your namespace or class name.

Answer (score 3):

Your call `new CreateDataSet.CreateDataSet()` wants to create an instance of the nested class `CreateDataSet.CreateDataSet`. If you want to call the constructor of `CreateDataSet` you should just use `new CreateDataSet()`.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the answer, if i do as you say i get the error: 'CreateDataSet' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: In that case, don't use the same name for a class and a namespace. You could circumvent the problem by using `global::` to qualify the name fully, but it's better to rename the class or namespace.